# What do you use to edit and develop Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, editor

What editors and tools do you use to develop in Classic ASP. I am currently use TextPad but its not great so I am looking for alternatives.

The problems that i am having with TextPad is that it seems to try to do syntax highlighting but it gets messed up which makes it hard to read. I feel like using a better  tool could be more productive.

Comment: You haven't described what you find missing or unsatisfying in TextPad. What are you looking for in an editor?

Comment: Anybody use eclipse for this??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some tools I've used:

- Visual Studio
- Notepad
- Ultra-Edit
- Notepad++
- ConText

Visual Studio (both for fee and free versions) works really nicely. Intellisense is a big plus. However any text editor that has code highlighting built in for asp all you really need.

I think you should get extra votes if you start using WinVI

Comment: +1: Notepad++ was the only ASP editor I ever needed.

Answer (score 4):

In 2000 (the only time I used it) I used Dreamweaver (I think it was version 4).

Comment: I'm actually using Dreamweaver right now on some classic ASP I'm doing, which is somewhat ironic because a) I'm primarily a ColdFusion developer and b) I've never used Dreamweaver before, I prefer Eclipse with the CFEclipse plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Back in the days I used Homesite http://www.adobe.com/products/homesite/

Comment: Perfect editor, I like it as much as Notepad !

Answer (score 2):

VIM is great because you don't have to be on a Windows box to use it.  If I'm looking for something easy to introduce somebody to I usually go with the free Komodo Edit.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Web Developer Express - Free download from Microsoft.

Emacs and vi are always good too.

Answer (score 2):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) IDE has fully configurable syntax highlighting but there is no default configuration for ASP.

But Zeus can import Textpad *syntax files* so to it should be fairly easy to configure it for ASP using your current Textpad configuration details.

Answer (score 1):

I also use emacs, but sometimes Ultraedit does the job for me.

Comment: UltraEdit is not free though :)

Answer (score 1):

Expression Web from Microsoft seems to get the job done. Although I'm not using it to write classic asp, sometimes when I open up .asp files, highlighting seems to be in place. (and it's a great html editor anyway IMO)

[Expression Web2](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/overview.aspx?key=web)

Answer (score 1):

When I developed classic ASP in 2001/02, I used EditPlus.

Comment: +1 Same story here. Still a great editor.  If it was a little more comfortable to use in Wine, I'd probably still be using it.

Answer (score 1):

We used [Visual Interdev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_InterDev) as our ASP 3.0 development environment. It had debugging capabilities and code completion however that was around 5 years ago so I expect there are better options available now.

Comment: That is the same tool I used to create Classic ASP pages back in the day.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs would be my choice but it can be quite daunting for new users.

A lisp extension for adding a major mode for editing ASP/JSP/PHP/HTML can be found [here](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html)

Comment: Yes, Emacs is available for Windows: 

http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html

Answer (score 0):

Allaire [HomeSite](http://www.adobe.com/products/homesite/) used to be really good, until it got bought by Macromedia, which then got bought by Adobe.  The code editing features got somewhat merged into Dreamweaver which is 10x slower, and although Adobe still sells HomeSite, it doesn't appear to be an actively developed product anymore.  There haven't been any updates in a very long time.  It's also a little buggy and crashes quite often (probably due to the fact that it hasn't been updated in ages).

Also tried [WeBuilder 2008](http://www.blumentals.net/webuilder/) briefly, but also found it to be quite buggy and crashed frequently, though it's got a good set of features and feels like a newer and better version of Homesite.

I've used [Ultra-Edit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) in the past, which has lots of useful features and worked fairly well, and [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) is also a good free application, though it seems better suited to quick changes rather than a full-blown IDE for Classic ASP development.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio 2008 SP1 re-added support for Classic ASP](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-framework-3-5-service-pack-1-beta.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda) is excellent if you're on a Mac.  There are syntax highlighters available for ASP as well.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a good editor (highlighting, collapsing, completion) for ASP, really.

When you open an ASP document, Notepad++ allows you to collapse functions and script blocks, but not HTML elements, even if you set the Language to HTML! (When you open a .htm file in Notepad++, it does allow you to collapse those elements though.)

The VS 2008 text editor is the other way around - HTML elements are fair game but not ASP code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 for me, used to use Ultra Edit but as soon as I got 2008 i stopped using it.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2005 works good.  so does 2003

Answer (score 0):

I use EditPlus (www.editplus.com) very simple with color and tab coding and very good search and replace functionality including regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I work on mac and after some time looking for something similar to notepad++ found one that really works for me.

[Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.com)